# wp_query display posts based on day

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am trying to get all posts to be displayed on a certain date.

For example today Tuesday I want all posts to be displayed.  It doesn't matter that the posts were created today (Tuesday) or last week or last year  - I just want a loop that will display all post of the current day.

Tomorrow (Wednesday) I want all post to be displayed.

I have created this code but it isn't working for me and I am getting a little frustrated.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$day = date('j');
query_posts( 'day='.$current_day);
query_posts('cat=9&posts_per_page=2' );

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post(); ?> 
        <div id="eventTitle">
            <span class="thetimeevent">
                <?php the_field('time'); ?>
            </span>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="eventFeed">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Comment: Please don't use `query_posts`. I'm almost certain I once told you this before. Might be wrong though. Use `WP_Query`. BTW, you cannot use two instances of `query_posts` the way you did.

Comment: Hey Pieter, I did use WP Query before but after many good searches I kept finding query_post. I am with you that using wp_query is much better.  I cannot for the life of me figure this out! Thanks again.

Comment: On which page/template are you using your code

Comment: I am creating a custom theme and it is on a custom homepage.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-posts-published-on-a-certain-day-of-the-week)

Comment: Thank you Pieter for this link I will have a look and if any good will report my finding. Thank you.